# Some doubts on a constraint

Tags: sqlite

I have 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Service (
id_ser integer PRIMARY KEY,
description char(256),
id_emp integer NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (id_emp) REFERENCES Employee(id_emp));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Employee (
id_emp integer PRIMARY KEY,
name char(50),
active boolean);
```

Each employee there is a bool column stating if he is active or not.

Every time I want to add another row to *Services* (via insert) I want to force that only employees with **True** in active are accepted.

I dunno how can I do this. If via check or by a trigger.

Comment: A real-world app could have something like a ScheduledServiceDate. What happens if the employee is used in a Service record while active but is then deactivated before the scheduled service date occurs? You would need application logic (like a trigger) to identify extant scheduled services involving that employee. With a database other than SQLite, I'd probably recommend stored procedures to handle this active/inactive logic.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a before trigger with a `SELECT RAISE` error if the employee is not active, like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS I_Service_Active 
    BEFORE INSERT ON Service
    BEGIN

        SELECT  RAISE(FAIL, 'Cannot insert Service record since Employee is not active')
        FROM    Employee E
        WHERE   E.id_emp = NEW.id_emp
          AND   NOT E.active;
    END;
```

You can't do the same thing with a constraint because that would require a subquery which is not allowed in a constraint expression.

Full example with test data:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Employee ( 
    id_emp integer PRIMARY KEY, 
    name char(50), 
    active boolean);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Service ( 
    id_ser integer PRIMARY KEY, 
    description char(256), 
    id_emp integer NOT NULL, 
    FOREIGN KEY (id_emp) REFERENCES Employee(id_emp)); 

CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS I_Service_Active 
    BEFORE INSERT ON Service
    BEGIN

        SELECT  RAISE(FAIL, 'Cannot insert Service record since Employee is not active')
        FROM    Employee E
        WHERE   E.id_emp = NEW.id_emp
          AND   NOT E.active;
    END;

INSERT INTO Employee (id_emp, name, active)
VALUES (1, 'Sam', 1);

INSERT INTO Employee (id_emp, name, active)
VALUES (2, 'John', 0);

-- SUCCEEDS
INSERT INTO Service (id_ser, description, id_emp)
VALUES (1, 'Sam Service', 1);

-- FAILS
INSERT INTO Service (id_ser, description, id_emp)
VALUES (2, 'John Service', 2);
```